# SQL Query translation to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Hello I am trying to translate the following relatively simple query to SQLAlchemy but I get

```
('Unexpected error:', <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError'>)

SELECT model, COUNT(model) AS count FROM log.logs 
WHERE SOURCE = "WEB" AND year(timestamp) = 2015 AND month(timestamp) = 1 
and account = "Test" and brand = "Nokia" GROUP BY model ORDER BY count DESC limit 10
```

This is what I wrote but it is not working. What is wrong ?

```
  devices = db.session.query(Logs.model).filter_by(source=source).filter_by(account=acc).filter_by(brand=brand).\
            filter_by(year=year).filter_by(month=month).group_by(Logs.model).order_by(Logs.model.count().desc()).all()
```

Comment: is the `count()` call here correct? `Logs.model.count().desc()` should it be ordering by the `count` column?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell from your code sample, but the following is hopefully the correct SQLAlchemy code.  Try:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

devices = (db.session
           .query(Logs.model, func.count(Logs.model).label('count'))
           .filter(source=source)
           .filter_by(account=acc)
           .filter_by(brand=brand)
           .filter_by(year=year)
           .filter_by(month=month)
           .group_by(Logs.model)
           .order_by(func.count(Logs.model).desc()).all())
```

Note that I've enclosed the query in a `(...)` to avoid having to use `\` at the end of each line.